What is the information density of factual knowledge in large bodies of English text?
An ML paper I was reading mentioned an estimate of no more than 0.7 bits per word, in footnote 4:

As of February 1, 2024, English Wikipedia contains a total of 4.5 billion words [...] We estimate that the non-overlapping contents of English textbooks have fewer than 16 billion words in total, see
Remark G.1. This amounts to 20.5 billion words, and we believe they contain fewer than 14 billion bits of knowledge.

but gave no references.
The authors define knowledge in the sense of tuples, like in the knowledge graph e.g. (Anya Forger, birthday, 10/2/1996).
Still, 0.7 bits per word seems surprisingly low. Are there any other numerical estimates of the information density of factual knowledge in large bodies of English text?

There are a vast amount of studies; the Wikipedia page is probably as good a start as any. There are quite a few different posts about the entropy of English scattered across different Stack Exchange sites; I've no idea if this is the best place or not to ask, but you should do some more research.

@StuartF "a few different posts about the entropy of English" But that's not what the question is about. The entropy of text is about 12 bits per word. The authors are talking about a small fraction of that - the "knowledge" part of it.
